# Find the last day of the month?

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm looking to find the last day of the month given a date field. Is there a better way to do this? For example, 01/07/2014 would return 01/31/2014, 02/08/2014 would return 02/28/2014, and so on.

```
if month({@end-date}) = 1 then 
  if day({@end-date}) = 1 then
    dateadd("d",30,{@end-date})
  else if day({@end-date}) = 2 then
    dateadd("d",29,{@end-date})
  else if day({@end-date}) = 3 then
    dateadd("d",28,{@end-date})
  else if day({@end-date}) = 4 then
    dateadd("d",27,{@end-date})
  else if day({@end-date}) = 5 then
    dateadd("d",26,{@end-date})
  else if day({@end-date}) = 6 then
    dateadd("d",25,{@end-date})
  else if day({@end-date}) = 7 then
    dateadd("d",24,{@end-date})
  else if day({@end-date}) = 8 then
    dateadd("d",23,{@end-date})
  else if day({@end-date}) = 9 then
    dateadd("d",22,{@end-date})
  else if day({@end-date}) = 10 then
    dateadd("d",21,{@end-date})
  else if day({@end-date}) = 11 then
    dateadd("d",20,{@end-date})
  else if day({@end-date}) = 12 then
    dateadd("d",19,{@end-date})
  else if day({@end-date}) = 13 then
    dateadd("d",18,{@end-date})
  else if day({@end-date}) = 14 then
    dateadd("d",17,{@end-date})
  else if day({@end-date}) = 15 then
    dateadd("d",16,{@end-date})
  else if day({@end-date}) = 16 then
    dateadd("d",15,{@end-date})
  else if day({@end-date}) = 17 then
    dateadd("d",14,{@end-date})
  else if day({@end-date}) = 18 then
    dateadd("d",13,{@end-date})
  else if day({@end-date}) = 19 then
    dateadd("d",12,{@end-date})
  else if day({@end-date}) = 20 then
    dateadd("d",11,{@end-date})
  else if day({@end-date}) = 21 then
    dateadd("d",10,{@end-date})
  else if day({@end-date}) = 22then
    dateadd("d",9,{@end-date})
  else if day({@end-date}) = 23 then
    dateadd("d",8,{@end-date})
  else if day({@end-date}) = 24 then
    dateadd("d",7,{@end-date})
  else if day({@end-date}) = 25 then
    dateadd("d",6,{@end-date})
  else if day({@end-date}) = 26 then
    dateadd("d",5,{@end-date})
  else if day({@end-date}) = 27 then
    dateadd("d",4,{@end-date})
  else if day({@end-date}) = 28 then
    dateadd("d",3,{@end-date})
  else if day({@end-date}) = 29 then
    dateadd("d",2,{@end-date})
  else 
    dateadd("d",1,{@end-date})
```

Comment: Please say you didn't write this by hand.

Comment: Please properly format this code and add some contextual information.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `DateSerial()` function to build your EOM date from the original date pretty easily. What this code basically does is finds the first day of the next month and then goes back a day to give you the end of the current month. You'll probably want to check the official documentation on the function to clarify what's going on.

```
DateSerial
(
 year({table.date}, //year
 month({table.date}) + 1, //the following month
 1 - 1 //days; go back one day from the first of the following month
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would sum one month, then subtract the day part. The formula below shall do the work.

```
NumberVar dayOfMonth := DatePart ("d", {Result.DataContrato});
DateTimeVar sameDayNextMonth := DateAdd ("m", 1, {Result.DataContrato});
DateTimeVar lastDayOfMonth := DateAdd("d", -dayOfMonth, sameDayNextMonth);
lastDayOfMonth
```

Just another option.